# Can an infinitive modifies an adverb

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english

His best form of expression in  mockery is to laugh awkwardly

Since to laugh is an infinitive therefore it's a noun and adverb never modifies a noun
So in this case ; Is to laugh a verb ?
Please clear this out .

Comment: I think you are a little confused about adverb use and  placement. Adverbs modify verbs, not the other way around, and they may placed either before or after the verb.

Comment: Is this statement grammatically correct

Comment: So an infinitive does not modifies an adverb

Comment: No, "...adverbs modify verbs, adjectives, or other adverbs." ...courtesy of my 4th grade grammar teacher, Miss Howe.

Comment: An infinitive works as a noun in a sentence

Comment: One should not use the word 'always' in a question about English.

Comment: While an infinitive can work as a noun (the concept of that action), that is not its main purpose. Its first job is to act as the core of a verb. Knowing the infinitive form starts you off in the standard rules of conjugating for a regular verb. Spanish has infinitives ending in *ar* and *er*. French, the eight *etre* verbs.

Comment: I think that saying "infinitive is/works as a noun" is a bit of a stretch. It is not a noun, it is an infinitive. What you probably mean is that infinitive can work as a subject. Here: "To laugh awkwardly is his best form of expression in mockery".

"

Comment: To laugh awkwardly is his best form of expression in mockery. Even in this case the adverb is modifying the infinite /the subject .

Comment: I'd say that the adverb "awkwardly" modifies the verb "laugh".

Comment: Does an infinitive works as an adverb.                              To win,you need the highest number of marks

Answer (score 1):

> Since to laugh is an infinitive therefore it's a noun

This is inaccurate: "An infinitive **may act** as a noun". Interestingly, infinitives were originally included in the class of "gerunds" as they have a substantive quality about them:

**To leave** *quickly* would be a mistake. / **Leaving** *quickly* would be a mistake.

Here you can see the verbal nature of the gerund: they are modified by adverbs.

Compare this to a common noun:

A **quick** **departure** would be a mistake. in which a "real" noun is modified by an adjective.

OED

> **gerund, n**.  A form of the Latin verb capable of being construed as a noun, but retaining the regimen of the verb.
>
> 1542   Introd. Eyght Partes Speche sig. Ciii   There be moreouer belongynge to the infinityue mode of verbes certayne voyces, called gerundes..[which] haue bothe the actiue and passiue signification.

*(Current Modern English = "Moreover, there are certain parts of speech that relate to the infinitive of verbs: these are called gerunds, which appear in both the active and passive voice.)*

You will see the OED reference to Latin - this is not too important as the reason is that in earlier times, English was supposed to be based on Latin - this is not the case.

It would have probably been better to call the gerund an infinitive as it does not have a tense, but this opportunity has been missed and English is stuck with infinitives and gerunds.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence
Leaving quickly would be a mistake.

(Leaving act as a present participle that works as an adjective therefore quickly modifies leaving )

To leave quickly would be a mistake.

( Here, To leave act as an adverbial infinitive therefore quickly modifies to leave )

Comment: Shouldn't your original question be 'Can an adverb modify an infinitive?'?

Comment: Shouldn't your original question be 'Can an adverb modify an infinitive?'?  /// Quirk et al take a stance that 'gradience' is the best way to analyse behaviour exhibited by say 'Miro's deftly painting his son was a joy to behold'. 'Painting' comes in a Saxon genitive construction (cf Peter's bike) but is modified by the adverb 'deftly'. The gradience POS tagging is 'somewhere along the noun-verb continuum'. _The same would apply with_ 
 'His usual response is to laugh awkwardly' _etc._